# How to make height relative to width

Tags: html, css

I want to make my height depending on the width, The **smaller** the width, the **higher** the height as in keeping a constant surface area of the element. How can I achieve that using only CSS?

```
height: calc(???)
```

None of the answer of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) is answering my question. I don't need it to have a constant aspect ratio but a constant surface area.

Answer (score 0):

Here height automatically becomes half of the width. `--box-width:300px` and `/2` changeable.

```css
:root {
  --box-width: 300px;
}

.box {
  width:var(--box-width);
  height:calc(var(--box-width)/2);
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to have a fixed width variable.

Comment: then use vw or %

Comment: `height: calc(20vw / 2);` it has opposite effect

Comment: this is working: https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/rQEgoV i don't understand you what the want.

Comment: what I want is the pink box's height will keep expand when sizing down the window's width. (smaller the width = higher the height and vise versa)